# Cant get Information out of request data (Django/Postman)

Tags: django, api, http, postman

Im trying to build an api with Django. I think i build it correctly but from, for example Post-request data, i get as the field values "none"
Maybe you can help me to solve this problem :)

Heres the api:

```
def apiRequests(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print(request.POST.get("name"))
        print(request.POST.get("publisher"))
        print(request.POST.get("price"))
        #Game.objects.create(name= request.POST.get('name'),publisher = request.POST.get("publisher"),price = request.POST.get("price"))
    elif request.method == "GET":
        response = Game.objects.filter(name = request.GET.get("name"))
    return render(request,"apirequests.html")
```

As you may see i'm printing out the data i receive. This looks like this:

```
None
None
None
[26/Aug/2022 08:40:09] "POST /api/ HTTP/1.1" 200 263
```

Here's the model class:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    publisher = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.BigIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + " " + self.name
```

And here is the data I'm sending as a Post-request from Postman to the api:

```
{
    "name": "FarCry",
    "publisher": "EA",
    "price": "35.66"
}
```

I think i should say that i got Problems with the CsrfViewMiddleware-Token so i commented it out in the settings.py, maybe there is the problem.
Thanks for helping

Comment: Are you sure you are executing POST request? From your question it looks like you are doing GET request at /api/ path

Comment: Copy-Pasted wrong sorry updated version above @TrueGopnik

Comment: Is there anything in request.POST? How are you sending data from postman, as raw data with JSON marked or form-data?

Comment: request.POST[...] equals the solution above. I send it as a raw Json file from the Postman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Postman, send the body as form-data.